# Android Activity Stack( BaseActivity)

Tags: android, android-activity

I Have Activities A, B, C. All extends base Activity.
I have a functionality when network is disconnect I need to close all my current activities and launch new activity showing message network is disconnected.
Before launching this activity I need to complete the work of the activity which is on top. **So I have registered broadcast receiver in base activity and created abstract method named `logout` and body is given in all the activity.**

Now when I launch activity A-> B-> C and disconnect network, `logout` method from activity A is getting called instead of C. Can anyone help me to understand this.

Comment: Can you should the code in BaseActivity where you register, unregister and call method `logout`?

Comment: Register the broadcast receiver at manifest level. This way you'll be able to get the broadcasted response in each "listening" activity. You can define the logout method in activity A, call it from B and C with some additional code in broadcast onReceive callback. More info here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers

Comment: for wifi i have custom view which do all the work for me problem is with base activity wrong method call

Comment: Please p[ost the code you use to register the `BroadcastReceiver`. If you register it in each `Activity`, then the `BroadcastReceiver` will be called in each `Activity`, in series (one after another).